# Using a variable as the entire action in gawk

Tags: variables, awk, action, gawk

I have a large number of multi column files that need to be awked into smaller files by column quickly.  The fastest way I've found to do this (so far) is the following:

```
gawk '{print $3, $2 >> "period.chidrop"; print $4, $2 >> "Tconj.chidrop"; print $5, $2 >> "oc.chidrop"}' generation.1*
```

My problem is that he action needs to be dynamic, but I can't seem to get a variable to work as the entire action.

Example:

```
gawkcmd='print $3, $2 >> "period.chidrop"; print $4, $2 >> "Tconj.chidrop"; print $5, $2 >> "oc.chidrop"'
gawk -v gawkcmd="$gawkcmd" '{gawkcmd}' generation.1*
```

This executes without an error message, but no files are produced.  I can print the string:

```
gawk -v gawkcmd="$gawkcmd" 'BEGIN{print gawkcmd}{gawkcmd}' generation.1*
```

but the command won't execute within the action.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: Do you want each column data in separate files?

Comment: @DevPa Correct (mostly).  The first column is always ignored and the second column is always printed along with one of the remaining columns.  It needs to be dynamic as column order can change from directory to directory.

Comment: To be more clear, can you pls provide sample input /output

Answer (score 0):

The last example does not work because the program is not a variable. As written (with a space between the `-v gawkcmd="$gawkcmd"` and `'BEGIN { print gawkcmd } { gawkcmd }`, it evaluates the variable on each line, but that doesn't do any printing (although it suppresses the default printing).

You're close though; you can use:

```
gawk "{ ${gawkcmd} }" generation.1*
```

where the braces around `${gawkcmd}` are optional, but emphasize that it isn't all a typo.

Comment: Sorry, that was a transcription typo. The space is there in my script.

This seems to work perfectly.  I'll have to play with it a bit to see if I can get conditionals to work as well, but thank you so much!